# MongoDB replica set storage difference in primary and Secondary node

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

Mongodb Replica set(PSA)(commumity edition 6.0 version) my secondary node one database size is 560 GB and same database in primary node 500 GB.. help explain and help out

i will check the db.stats() and indexes number also same

```
primary db.stats()
 collections: 21,
  views: 0,
  objects: Long("4251179487"),
  avgObjSize: 333.0748902272825,
  dataSize: 1415961140969,
  storageSize: 393951244288,
  indexes: 48,
  indexSize: 178265362432,
  totalSize: 572216606720,
  scaleFactor: 1,
  fsUsedSize: 659525169152,
  fsTotalSize: 965895835648,
  ok: 1,



secondary db.stats()
 collections: 21,
  views: 0,
  objects: Long("4251179487"),
  avgObjSize: 333.0748902272825,
  dataSize: 1415961140969,
  storageSize: 423536803840,
  indexes: 48,
  indexSize: 182481330176,
  totalSize: 606018134016,
  scaleFactor: 1,
  fsUsedSize: 688594571264,
  fsTotalSize: 965895835648,
  ok: 1,
```